# NMap to scan a private subnetwork

Tags: network, firewalls, nmap

I have a test network setup based on virtual machines. My host machine, a web server and the firewall is under the `192.168.0.0/24` network (gateway is `192.168.0.1`); a server machine is located behind the firewall on the `10.40.1.0/24` network (firewall eth1 is its gateway with IP `10.40.1.1`). Please note that the firewall has no rules at this point.

How can I use `nmap` to detect/scan the server behind the firewall on the `10.40.1.0/24` network?

Comment: Is your firewall on the 192.168 subnet actually a NAT router handling traffic for the 10.40 subnet?  If so, it is more than a firewall.

Comment: Yes, the 10.40 subnet uses the firewall to access the internet and the firewall has a NAT role when it comes to directing traffic inside de subnet.

Comment: If you can access the web server from a network, so can the nmap. If you are asking about the specific switches for Nmap, you can start at https://nmap.org/book/man.html

Answer (score 1):

The NAT software running on the Firewall system is going to block all inward traffic that doesn't match a current egress session or a port forwarding rule. If no port forwarding rules are in place, then the server behind the NAT is as good as invisible, barring compromises to the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

How to detect if you are behind a PNAT:

`nping --ec "public" -c 1 echo.nmap.org` (CAPT-labelled packet gives away the PNAT address)

If you test the external side of the firewall, you could use the [bnat](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/bnat/bnat_scan) modules from the Metasploit Framework in order to [route](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/bnat/bnat_router) traffic through the broken implementation of NAT.

There is also a vulnerability in some firewalls that leads to a bypass, detectable from an Nmap script -- https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/firewall-bypass.html.